# How to fix this OS X Dock Tooltip encoding problem?

Tags: macos, dock

I'm running Lion in French and have had the following bug in my Dock for the last couple of weeks. It doesn't go away if I reboot or kill the Dock.

Have you ever seen something like that before?

[image: My Dock's going crazy!]

Comment: What have you done to get this problem?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, nothing at all.

Comment: Oh, those problems are the best of all :)

Answer (score 1):

You could find the strings file (which holds the translations) and do a search and replace on nonstandard characters.

Comment: That sounds hackish :)

Comment: It's only a little hackish. You're better of doing that than messing with finder.